# Hardware Random Number Generator for PHP

Tags: php, linux, random, generator

I have a PHP script and need to generate about 30 to 60 random numbers (min 1 / max 6) each second for a dice game.

What is the best affordable solution in terms of hardware ? VPS + Hardware RNG

Is this even possible to connect a Hardware RNG to a VPS ? and if so, which Hardware RNG is the most suitable to use with/trough PHP scripting ?

Edit: I will hunt for a Cigital certificate for the RNG.

Comment: You should ask yourself whether you really need a hardware RNG. I highly doubt that a CSPRNG like `/dev/urandom` is not sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Edit: I will hunt for a Cigital certificate for the RNG. Don't know if I can a certificate by using the /dev/urandom

Answer (score 1):

This question is best suited for a different stack exchange site, but your best bet is having a TRNG seed a PRNG, and then have those be your random numbers. If you are running Linux, there is a TRNG in /etc/ which you could then use for this purpose.

Comment: Please, could you advise me in which site I should post this question? I have edited the query. Rgrds